Qt - set a GUI region as a not "empty area" for KDE Plasma
I have a Qt5/6 GUI application (C++) that uses a QVTK render window to display a point cloud.
Under Kubuntu Linux, the default desktop (Plasma/composer?) behaviour allows moving the entire app pane if the user clicks and drags somewhere in the GUI that isn't an "interactable" thing like a button. This interferes with the VTK viewport because in addition to drag-to-rotate, the entire app is dragged instead, and the mouse release event doesn't propagate to the viewport so it continues to rotate when the button is released. I don't know if this is specifically a Linux problem or if it's due to the way the widget is set up. This is also only a left click problem - rotation and panning work fine as they use middle/right click events.
Clearly there's some overridden behaviour for other widgets like QPushButton, though apparently not for QLabels. I don't know if I explicitly need to capture mouse events within the layout that holds the viewport, or if there's a general qApplication flag I can set that disables drag behaviour on background regions. I'd still like to be able to interact with the viewport so just ignoring mouse events doesn't work.
It seems like one option is to disable Plasma's drag behaviour, but I'm interested to know if there's a global solution to this so I don't have to rely on a user's specific desktop config.

What counts as a "non empty" area?

If I remember correctly, the platform plugin checks for empty areas in specific containers (QFrame and QGroupBox at least, IIRC). If you use a pure QWidget subclass and accept mouse press events, there shouldn't be any problem.

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe I found the culprit: https://github.com/KDE/qtcurve/blob/master/qt5/style/windowmanager.cpp
